# Dont know how to loop through types in DbContext calling ToListAsync generically

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-core

I have a DbContext with a property Countries

```
public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
```

I want to use reflection to call the `ToListAsync` method for each type in my context

Im working towards a method that will take a snapshot of all the tables in a DbContext including filtering expressions.  The filtering is already dealt with using the EntityQueryFilterHelper

I am using Ef Core for .NET Core 3.1

Thanks to the help in the answer I now have the code

```
var contextDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var allCountries = await this.Countries.ToListAsync();
var firstCountry = allCountries.FirstOrDefault();

var filters = new List<FilterObject>
{
    new FilterObject() {PropertyName = "Name", PropertyValue = firstCountry.Name}
};

var entityTypes = this.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Country"));

foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
{
    var requiredType = entityType.GetType();
    var filter = EntityQueryFilterHelper.CreateFilter<Country>(filters);
    var allItems = from x in this.Countries select x;
    var filteredItems = filter(allItems);
    var method = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync))?.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Country));
    var toListAsyncResult = (Task<List<Country>>) method?.Invoke(null, new object[] {filteredItems, default(CancellationToken)});
    if (toListAsyncResult != null)
    {
        var result = await toListAsyncResult;
        contextDictionary.Add("Countries", result);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly - so the next question is how to change the above to make use of the EntityType instead of it being hard coded

Can anyone help please?

Paul

Comment: `method?.Invoke` is stupid. method mustn't be `null`. If it is `null` then it is an error in the reflection code, so the `Invoke` must crash.

Comment: This looks like a bad approach. Why do you want to take this snapshot, and why through reflection? Can't you just call .Set<T>().ToListAsync()?

Comment: @xanatos I will remove that - fair point

Comment: @CodeCaster I want a snapshot because I want to go through all of my tables get the data according to the filter requirements, or all of the contents and bring the data into memory.  I will then be saving it to json to form a snapshot of the entire context which I can then save to json (the database is not big) This json can then be used within unit tests.  I dont want to set anything I want to get the data

Comment: How would you retrieve the filters? Or do you have a single `filters` obejct that is good for all the `DbSet<>`?

Comment: I will have a dictionary as a parameter.  This dictionary contains the key which is the name of the Entity Type and the value which is the Filters object.  I excluded that from the example above to try to avoid complicating it more, but basically all I need to do is to get the filters object from my parameter for the type that I am processing.  The EntityQueryFilterHelper will deal with creating the expression that contains the actual filter that part is all fine.  The sample above is obviously not 100% realistic.  I now need to call all of the methods using requiredType instead of Country

Answer (score 0):

The `ToListAync()` is in the class [`EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.tolistasync?view=efcore-5.0), so

```
var method = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync)).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Country));
```

and it is `static`, so:

```
var result = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { this.Countries, default(CancellationToken) });
```

Where `result` is a `Task<List<Country>>` that is a `Task`.

To call it is hard :-) Technically calling the method is easy... extracting the result is hard. If you want to go full-dynamic it gets hard quickly:

```
var t = (Task)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { context.Blogs, default(CancellationToken) });
await t;
var ilist = (IList)((dynamic)t).Result;
```

and now you a non-generic `IList`, so its elements are `object`. But in the end you are going in the wrong direction. If you want to go in the "right" direction, make a :

```
public static async void DoWorkOnMyIQueryable<T>(IQueryable<T> dbset)
{
    List<T> res = await dbset.ToListAsync();

    foreach (var el in res)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

and call the `DoWorkOnMyIQueryable` through reflection. Now at least you have a typed `List<T>`!

Now that you have written your full question, as often it is, it was an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

As I've written, it is much easier to build a single generic method that is based around a generic `TEntity` and then use reflection to call it.

The method:

```
public static class Tools
{
    public static async Task<IList> ExtractData<TEntity>(DbContext context, List<FilterObject> filters) where TEntity : class
    {
        var dbset = context.Set<TEntity>();
        var filter = EntityQueryFilterHelper.CreateFilter<TEntity>(filters);
        var filtered = filter(dbset);

        return await filtered.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

And now to call it:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, IList>> GenerateContextDictionary()
{
    var filters = new List<FilterObject>();
    // Here prepare your filters

    var entityTypes = this.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("Country"));

    var method = typeof(Tools).GetMethod(nameof(Tools.ExtractData), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

    var contextDictionary = new Dictionary<string, IList>();

    foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
    {
        var method2 = method.MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType);
        var ilist = await (Task<IList>)method2.Invoke(null, new object[] { this, filters });
        contextDictionary.Add(entityType.Name, ilist);
    }

    return contextDictionary;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this later

Comment: is the expression part possible?

Comment: Your question is too much unclear. Can't answer.

Comment: Ok I will clarify later

Comment: Added more information to the question, this doesnt work

Comment: @Paul Made correction.

Comment: Thanks @xanatos please see amended info this is getting a lot closer now, just need to see how to call this in a true async way and how I can get my hard coded types replaced with the type in a loop

Comment: @paul expanded the response with example about how to call the method, and another simpler way to do everything.

Comment: there was a crossover I added a lot more to the details given the current logic before I saw this

Comment: @Paul Written some code for your new question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227734/discussion-between-paul-and-xanatos).